# How to selectively import Framework and implement extension based on iOS version?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have an iOS app written in Swift that needs to run on iOS 13 and later.

The problem:

1. I have two frameworks, one that is only present in iOS 13 SDK and another that is only in iOS 14 SDK
2. For each framework, I need to implement an extension to perform a certain task

The question:

1. How can I selectively import the correct framework depending on whether it's running on iOS 13 or iOS 14? I looked into `@available`, `canImport`, `#if defined`, but none does what I described above
2. How can I go about implementing the extensions so that the correct extension would be used and compiler not yell at me?

Comment: Import is encoded into binary at build time, but  loading of dynamic library happens in runtime. Are you saying that you want to selectively load different frameworks in runtime?

Comment: Well I'm not sure if this is possible but the end goal is to have one Swift file that has import statements for both frameworks (maybe using compile time filter like @available too choose which import statement to execute).

Comment: And that Swift file would also have extension implementations for both frameworks, but also filtered out during compile time depending on iOS version

Comment: This might help you to load frameworks and symbols from your frameworks in runtime selectively https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/ea67a5c30b5b5cb8d6b53db7a073d7eccbedf2db/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/FBSDKDynamicFrameworkLoader.m

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't import depending on a specific OS version, but you can use `canImport`.

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
  // UIKit code
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
  // AppKit code
#else
  // Other Code
#endif
```

> The way canImport works is if the module exists in your search paths,
> it'll be true. - [Swift forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-exclude-a-local-package-from-an-xcode-target/53919/4)